# Overlay HTML radio button on video

Tags: html, css, html5-video, overlay

I would like to **overlay** HTML radio buttons on top of a video such that you can select them. I know the coordinates of the pixels for each of the coloured box if that helps. Like in the example below, the black circles would represent the radio buttons that I can click. How do I format it using CSS? [image]

```
<style>
  #container {
      width: 428px;
      height: 200px;
      position: relative;
  }

  #overlay {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50px;
      left: 50px;
      color: red;
      font-size: 40px;
      z-index: 10;
  }

  #base {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0px;
      left: 0px;
  }
</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="overlay">
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="white" value="1" />
          <input type="radio" name="white" value="2" />
          <input type="radio" name="white" value="3" />
          <input type="radio" name="white" value="4" />
          <input type="button" id="continue" value="Continue"/>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div id="base">
        <video controls>
          <source src="videos/event_0_Junli_Standing_20150322_181647_00_0.6.mp4" type="video/mp4">
          Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: Please include a full sample of your code so we can see what you have and what you've tried.

Comment: @Ryan done! Please remove your down vote.

Comment: @Ryan do you know how would I position them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best bet would just be to have the radio buttons in `position: absolute` and move them over the video with `top:` and `right:`.

[JSfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e3hwzptd/)

Comment: Thank you for that demo, I've got it working but how do I position the buttons such that they are on specific areas of the video?

Comment: @AlexKer What do you mea by specific areas? At specific time points or how specific do you need to be with the position of them?

Comment: They will not be moving around. If you look at the image I want the buttons on top of each coloured box. I know the coorindates for those in pixels.

Comment: they should remain in those positions that I set them throughout the video. I want to position all the radio buttons right on top of the coloured boxes. In the picture the black circle represent where I want them. I have the coordinates for the boxes if that helps. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexKer As I said, you will have to use the `top;` and `right:` css attribute to change their position (try it out on JSfiddle) and also try to add margin between the radio buttons themself to get them to the right position.